# Writing out comma separated values inside a single cell in a spreadsheet using python

Tags: python

Please excuse the long subject header. I have gotten pretty good at writing data out to csv files but i seem to have stumbled into this block. Anytime a ',' (comma) is used to join values, it shifts over to the next cell in the spreadsheet. What I want to accomplished is for example:

Inside a single cell, write out cat,dog,mouse

Already checked the csv module in python docs and nothing immediately jumped out at me.

any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what your source data looks like, but if you can use python to add (") in front of and behind every string the delineation should work correctly.  In other words you want to see "cat, dog, mouse" instead of cat, dog, mouse.

Comment: Show your code :)

Comment: There's not a lot of GIS in this, try stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4):

The Python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) can handle these edge cases. The module also supports all different kinds of delimiters, not just commas. Assuming that this is our input data where the third element has a literal comma in the string:

```
OutputRow = ["one", "two", "three, four"]
```

Using the basic text writer, the output row is incorrectly interpreted as four columns:

```
with open("Output.txt","wb") as Output_txt:
    Output_txt.write(",".join(OutputRow))
```

> `one,two,three, four`

Using the CSV writer, the output row is correctly interpreted as three columns. It uses the double quotes to denote that any contained commas should be treated as literal commas.

```
import csv
with open("Output.csv","wb") as Output_csv:
    CSVWriter = csv.writer(Output_csv)
    CSVWriter.writerow(OutputRow)
```

> `one,two,"three, four"`

Don't be afraid of using the `csv` module. It is incredibly fast and flexible, with other useful features like [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). I seldom ever use the normal text reader in Python.